# Implement "File open in folder" feature for my C++ application in linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, fork

I'm trying to implement the "Open In Folder" functionality that you seen in firefox and download managers. This is the code that I've come up so far, and I decided to use nautilux program to open the file.

```
int File::openTempFile(std::string temp_file_dir)
{
  std::string file_path = temp_file_dir + "/" ;
  file_path = file_path + this->additional_info ;

  // if there is already an temporary file then delete it//
  if( temporary_file != "" )
  {
    // :TODO: open temporary file stack //
    // so when the application dinit we could remove those //
    // remove(temporary_file.c_str() );
  } 

  /* write temporary file */
  FILE* fp = fopen (file_path.c_str(), "w");
  if( fp== NULL)
    return FALSE;
  fwrite( m_data, 1, m_size, fp);
  fclose(fp); 

  // now open it using natulus //
  char * parmList[] = {strdup("nautilus"),strdup(file_path.c_str() )} ;
  int pid;
  if(( pid= fork() ) == -1) 
    perror("fork failed");
  if( pid ==0 ){
    int a = execvp("nautilus" , parmList);
    printf("exevp failed to load the temporary file");
  }
  temporary_file = file_path ;
  return TRUE;
}
```

but the error is natulux open three windows and can't figure out where is my bug.
Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried running `nautilus your-file-name` from the command line before writing code?

Comment: On Linux it is spelled "directory", not "folder" !